# Can't install NVIDIA drivers after I accidentally removed them

Tags: nvidia, 21.04, additional-drivers

So, I accidentally uninstalled NVIDIA drivers with `apt autoremove`, I tried to reinstall it from "Software & Updates" app but all the options in Additional drivers are greyed out.

I don't want to manually install NVIDIA drivers using the packages from NVIDIA's website because it's very tedious and usually does not work, What should I do now?

My laptop is Lenovo IdeaPad L340 Gaming with Gtx1650, if that's required.
I'm running Ubuntu Desktop 21.04 latest stable release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more digging, I found that  `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` installed NVIDIA drivers for me and now my device went back to normal, I rechecked if `apt autoremove` will again remove the drivers, but it didn't this time.
I guess it was some bug during the installation during OS installation made the driver packages marked as unused.

Answer (score 0):

Try running these commands

```
sudo add-apt repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and finally,

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-430
```

Here, **`430`** is the version of nvidia driver, you can choose yours according to your nvidia driver.

Comment: Will this work with any Debian-based distro ?

Comment: @ArmiaKhairy Not necessarily. Debian itself does not support Launchpad PPA.